# Android - SalesForce marketing cloud SDK proguard/dexguard issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush-android, push-notification

I'm having a problem receiving callbacks from push notifications: when i'm in the production environment and with dexguard enabled.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init (Landroid/content/Context;Lcom/salesforce/marketingcloud/MarketingCloudConfig;)V in class Lcom/salesforce/marketingcloud/location/h; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.salesforce.marketingcloud.location.h' appears in /data/app/...-2Mvv..Ng2-m6i..m7A==/base.apk!classes3.dex)
       at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.location.f.a(:36)
       at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MarketingCloudSdk.a(:215)
       at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MarketingCloudSdk.a(:47)
       at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MarketingCloudSdk$a.run(:38)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

- I updated the library to 8.0.7, without success;
- I already added this ignore from the dexguard file to ignore the library;

```
### SALESFORCE
-keep class com.salesforce.marketingcloud.**{ *; }
```

None of the procedures worked, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Update the version of Google Play Service Location that you're including -- and/or make it match what is required as listed in the integration docs.

Comment: I already have the versions indicated as necessary: ​​Google Play Services (21.0.1) and Firebase (BOM-30.5.0)

Comment: Incorrect. Version 8.0.7 uses v19 of play services location. If you wish to use v21, please update to v8.0.9 of the SDK. ref. https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/#version-807